# Acess query: replace 2018 in Like "*2018*" with current year

Tags: ms-access

How do i adjust the query criteria `Like "*2018*"` to always match current year?

I have tried:

```
Like Year(Now())
Like "*Year(Now())*"
Like *Year(Now())*
Like "Year(Now())"
```

but either the query throws an error or returns empty table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the strings:

`Like "*" & Year(Now()) &  "*"`

Answer (score 2):

If you are applying this as criteria to a date field it will never match. You are comparing a year number to a complete date field

Assuming your date field is a date datatype, you need the WHERE clause to be something like

```
WHERE Year(YourDateField) = Year(Now())
```